# fetch result from database by array codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have a table of food where I store category ids as coma separated like in the below image
[food table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b48Cy.png)

I made a method in model which takes array (category ids) as argument and fetches the food items which have ids matching to the array from argument.

I made the below query

```
if(count($categoryIds) > 0 && count($allergyIds) == 0 ){
    $tempArr = array();
    foreach($categoryIds as $eachCategoryId){
        $sql = "Select food.food_id,food_name,food_image,food_thumbnail,description,food_variations.price as price,is_active
        from food
        join food_variations on food_variations.food_id = food.food_id
        where FIND_IN_SET($eachCategoryId,category_id)
        and food.restaurant_id = $restaurantId
        and food.is_active = 1
        and food.is_deleted = 0
        and food.food_status = 3
        and food_variations.food_variation_id = food.default_food_variation_id";
        $result = $this->db->query($sql)->result_array();
        array_push($tempArr, $result);
    }
    echo "<pre>";print_r($tempArr);
}
```

Below is the result of above query

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [food_id] => 10
                    [food_name] => Rama Mckee
                    [food_image] => 
                    [food_thumbnail] => 
                    [description] => asdfs
                    [price] => 34
                    [is_active] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [food_id] => 6
                    [food_name] => Rishi
                    [food_image] => 
                    [food_thumbnail] => 
                    [description] => test
                    [price] => 120
                    [is_active] => 1
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [food_id] => 5
                    [food_name] => test
                    [food_image] => http://localhost/gastroapp/assets/uploads/food_images/a5918726b920e7cbfc7f90e1afc48091.jpg
                    [food_thumbnail] => http://localhost/gastroapp/assets/uploads/food_images/thumb/a5918726b920e7cbfc7f90e1afc48091.jpg
                    [description] => test
                    [price] => 120
                    [is_active] => 1
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [food_id] => 10
                    [food_name] => Rama Mckee
                    [food_image] => 
                    [food_thumbnail] => 
                    [description] => asdfs
                    [price] => 34
                    [is_active] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [food_id] => 7
                    [food_name] => ezhva
                    [food_image] => 
                    [food_thumbnail] => 
                    [description] => ddsfsd
                    [price] => 20
                    [is_active] => 1
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [food_id] => 8
                    [food_name] => test
                    [food_image] => 
                    [food_thumbnail] => 
                    [description] => test
                    [price] => 22
                    [is_active] => 1
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [food_id] => 6
                    [food_name] => Rishi
                    [food_image] => 
                    [food_thumbnail] => 
                    [description] => test
                    [price] => 120
                    [is_active] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

I am getting duplicate results and I think this might also cause performance issues.

The below was the query when I had only one category per food which was giving me desired result.

```
return $this->db->select('food.food_id,food_name,food_image,food_thumbnail,description,food_variations.price as price,is_active')
            ->from('food')
            ->join('food_variations', 'food_variations.food_id = food.food_id')
            ->where_in('category_id',$categoryIds)
            ->where('food.restaurant_id', $restaurantId)
            ->where('food.is_active', '1')
            ->where('food.is_deleted', '0')
            ->where('food.food_status','3')
            ->where('food_variations.food_variation_id IN( select food_variation_id from food_variations where food_variation_id = food.default_food_variation_id )')
            ->get()
            ->result_array();
```

Please help.

Comment: For mysql, string column is recommended for saving static data instead of adding just IDs.
Instead of just integer, you will have to store the object with relevant values.
If you want it's relational data, its better to use an intermediate table.

Comment: I have updated my question. Please have a look into it now.

Answer (score 0):

For mysql, string column is recommended for saving static data instead of adding just IDs. Instead of just integer, you will have to store the object with relevant values. If you want it's relational data, its better to use an intermediate table.

like U need an extra table `category_products` table to store `category_id` and `product_id` since You have `many-to-Many` relationships(a product have many category and a category have many products)

Answer (score 0):

First You need to insert your list in an array

```
$list = {ids column}
$list = array_map("intval", explode(",", str_replace(',' , '', $list)));
```

Now your list is saved in an array $list

Now you can call it

```
foreach($list as $value) {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM menu WHERE user_id = '$user_id' AND id = '$value' AND deleted = '0' AND active = '1';";
$result = mysqli_query($dBconnection, $sql);
$check = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($check>0) {

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
cho $row['id'];
}

} else {
echo 'empty list';
}
}
```